# не работает команда с рандомом

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу сделать такую команду: .random (минимальное число, максимальное число) пример: .random 50 60. Чтобы бот выводил рандомное число от 50 до 60 (или другие числа)

```
randin = 'in'
randout = 'out'
@bot.command()
async def randome(ctx, randin = False, randout =False):
    if randin == False:
        await ctx.send("Введите число от 1 до 100 000. Пример: 500 600")
    else:
     randomiz = (random.randint({randin}, {randout}))
     embedg = disnake.Embed(
     title = ("Рандомайзер"),
     description = (f'{randomiz}'),
     color = 0x08000
     )
     await ctx.send(embed=embedg)
```

Выводит такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
random.randint(50, 60) # функция генерирует случайное целое число от 50 до 60. вместо них могут быть любые числа.
```

Comment: Так я использую библиотеку рандом, только не знаю как сделать так чтобы бот отправлял рандомное число, с выбором мин. числа и макс. числа.

Comment: random.randint(input(), input())

Comment: А ой, мне нужно именно через чат, а не через консоль

Comment: @Timur Я этого и ожидал. Какую библиотеку вы используете? Telebot?

Comment: disnake.py.....

Comment: https://guide.disnake.dev/interactions/modals - можете посмотреть тут

Comment: https://docs.disnake.dev/en/v2.5.2/ext/commands/api.html - или тут

Comment: Вообще ничего конкретного про возможность ввода сообщений в этой библиотеке я не нашёл. В документации этого нет, а на StackOverflow по этой теме нет или почти нет вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было всего лишь добавить: min: int, max: int. И ничего лишнего

```
@bot.command()
async def rand(ctx, min: int, max: int):
  rando = random.randint(min, max)
  await ctx.send(rando)
```